# Central limit theorem and Slutsky

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Let $(A_i)$ be a series of positive iid random variables with $0 < E[A_1^2] < \infty$,

Let $(B_i)$ be a series of iid random variables independent of $(A_i)$ and $0 < \operatorname{Var}[B_1] < \infty$.

Then
$$X_n \xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{\operatorname{Var}[B_1]\,E[A_1^2]}{\left(E[A_1]\right)^2}\right) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty. $$
where
$$X_n = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_iB_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i}-E[B_1]\right).$$
The central limit theorem and the strong law of large numbers seem to come in handy, but somehow it doesn’t really work, since I can’t get the two parts separated in a way that I can apply both theorems to independent parts and then use Slutsky's theorem.

Can someone help?

Comment: you can replace $B_i$ with $B_i-EB_i$, so assume it has mean 0.  Then the CLT applies to the i.i.d. r.v.s $A_iB_i$, which have variance $Var(B) E(A^2)$, so you apparently you have a simple quote of slutsky to the effect of $\frac {A_1 + ... + A_n} n $ converges.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can rearrange the expression of $X_n$ multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt(n)$ to get

$$ X_n = \frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^nA_k} \cdot \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nA_k(B_k-E[B_k])}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Observe that you can apply the CLT to $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nA_k(B_k-E[B_k])}{\sqrt{n}}$ where your sequence is $(A_k(B_k -E[B_k]))_k$ and each term in this sequence has mean zero.

By the Law of Large Numbers $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nA_k}{n} \rightarrow E[A_1]$ a.s, hence converge in probability. Now, if $E[A_k] > 0$ you can apply Slutsky.